# Insert GIF in UITextView from PasteBoard and animate it

Tags: swift, animation, uitextview

Is there any way to insert Gif file in UITextView and animate it? I saw several examples but there I need the gif name, or split the gif into frames and again their names. I download the image from internet and copy it. I want to paste the image in a textview and animate the gif.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in imageView, hope it will work on textView also

```
 let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("splash_bg", withExtension: "gif")!)
    let imageGif = UIImage.gifWithData(imageData!)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageGif)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
```